# Using different types/format of _id ok?

Tags: couchdb

I'm using one database for all (users, files and comments).

I was wondering if I can/should use

- twitter user id for user doc _id's
- md5 hash (of file) for file doc _id's
- provided uuid for comment doc _id's

It feels weird to mix those different types of id's.

What speaks agains this scenario? Should I stick to the CouchDB uuid's for consistency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any format of id, or combination of formats, as you see fit. You might wish to add a prefix to ensure there are no overlaps between them, though.

```
twitter:@rnewson
md5:86f646c11b3bc7d434d06c077aee43d8
```

And so on.

Comment: Coming from MySql feels super weird to use uid like that :) BTW: followed you

Comment: Heh, understood. I think this is the point where we pull out the community mantra and remind you to "relax". :)